# How to change Boolean variable based on expression?

Tags: variables, expression, sh

I'm trying to change the value of a Boolean variable using expression in bash script (Debian Jessie) but it's not working as intended!
Here is my code

```
vld=true
while ! [ $vld ]
do
echo "Enter a number: [1-30]:"
read myinput
$vld=[ $myinput -ge 1 ] && [ $myinput -le 30 ]
done
echo "Your number is $myinput
```

When I this script it says:

```
8: ./test.sh true=[: not found
```

Then it keeps on the loop as the variable is not receiving the result of the expression but is used itself!

Comment: You don't have a boolean expression; `[` is a command name, not a grouping operator.

Comment: What would that be replaced with?